# HTML form validation not appearing

Tags: html, css, validation, bootstrap-4

New to all this but essentially I'm trying to use HTML form validation via browser defaults. The form uses a JQuery script to submit the form. I've trawled through similar posts and updated my code but still no luck. If I click the Subscribe button with nothing entered, then there's no prompts presented.

#### HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" id="sub-form">
          <div class="flex-fill mr-2">
            <div class="mc-form-group-FNAME" style="display: inline">
              <input type="name" class="form-control required" name="FNAME" id="mce-FNAME" value="" placeholder="First name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="mc-form-group-EMAIL" style="display: inline">
              <input type="email" class="form-control required email" name="EMAIL" id="mce-EMAIL" value="" placeholder="Email address" required />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="subscribe-btn" onclick="submitForm()">Subscribe</button>
          </div>
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_8a28f24e93a8a23b993145f05_2d6480ea6a" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        </form>
```

#### JQuery/JS

```
  //Mail Chimp form submission
  $('#sub-form').MailChimpForm({
    url: 'https://-.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=8a28f24e93a8a23b993145f05&amp;id=2d6480ea6a',
    fields: '0:FNAME,1:EMAIL',
    submitSelector: '#subscribe-btn',
    customMessages: {
      E001: 'This field can not be empty',
      E003: 'Please enter a valid email address',
    },
    onFail: (message) => {
      if ((message.indexOf("already") >= 0) || (message.indexOf("recent")) >=0) {
        alert('This email address is already subscribed. Stay tuned for our newsletter!')
      }
    },
    onOk: function() {
      $('#subscribe-ok').modal('show');
      $('#sub-form').each(function() {
        this.reset();
      });
    }
  });
```

#### UPDATE

So upon more testing the HTML validation works if I remove all the JQuery. As soon as I add it back in its gone. Any reason why my JS would break HTML validation?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Hi - no I'm afraid nothing there.

Comment: Interestingly seems to work with Firefox but not Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Validation works fine in my local machine

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Maybe here is your answer, Did you try this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902053/7894673)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the responses. In the end I opted for JQuery entirely and implemented `ToolTipster` and `JQuery Validate`. Final code below.

```
$("#sub-form").validate({
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
          var ele = $(element),
              err = $(error),
              msg = err.text();
          if (msg != null && msg !== "") {
              ele.tooltipster('content', msg);
              ele.tooltipster('open'); //open only if the error message is not blank. By default jquery-validate will return a label with no actual text in it so we have to check the innerHTML.
              console.log("form validation attempted")
          }
      },
      unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass).tooltipster('close');
      },
      rules: {
          field1: {
              required: true,
              email: false
          },
          field2: {
              required: true,
              email: true
          }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
          alert('valid form');
          return false;
      }
  });

//Run validation on form for subscribe attempt
  $('#subscribe-btn').click(function () {
    if ($("#sub-form").valid()) {
            console.log('hello - valid form');
        } else {
            console.log('uh oh invalid form');
        }
    });
```